# How to hide only soft keyboard android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, activitygroup, android-tabactivity

In my application i am using tab activity and activity group. In one of the activity i have edit texts. When the user click on the edit text, soft keyboard appears. But when the user click on the back button the soft key board dismisses and the previous activity on the activity stack appears.

Earlier on other application when i press back button when there is soft keyboard on the screen, only soft keyboard dismiss and it wouldn't go back to previous activity unless i press the back button again. I want this to happen in my current application as well. Plz Help.

Comment: which device are you using?

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar htc wild fire s

Comment: what is the version of android are you running... is this behavior consistent with other apps on device.. can you check this in other apps just be sure that HTC has not messed up this...

Comment: I m using android 2.3. Ya in other application its working fine. I think this may be due to activity group or tab activity. But still i m not able to get to the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
              this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {

            System.out.println("Software Keyboard was shown");

        } else {

             System.out.println("Software Keyboard is hidden");

             }
```

This does the trick. I checked if the  soft key board is opened it stays at the current activity, otherwise it goes to previous activity.

Answer (score 1):

Use below in your On create Method. it is working fine.

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

can try this-
 **

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

**

Answer (score 0):

**code**

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
  Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

check below link also :-

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
protected void hideSoftKeyboard(EditText input) {
        input.setInputType(0);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(input.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }
```